# Debug a Nginx vhost as a reverse proxy for a Uvicorn Python API

Tags: nginx, gunicorn

I have a (Python, DRF-based) API, running as a Uvicorn service on port 8002 on a Debian server.
It runs with no apparent issue, since when I do `curl http://127.0.0.1:8002/videos/`, I get the expected API response (I also have tested it when deployed on Heroku, with no issue).

I need to serve it publicly with Nginx, so I configured a new Nginx vhost as a reverse proxy as followed:

```
 upstream my_api {
     server 127.0.0.1:8002;
 }
 
 server {
 
     server_name example.com;
 
     location / {
         # Pass to Uvicorn/Gunicorn web server service
         proxy_pass http://my_api;
         proxy_set_header Host $host;
         proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
         proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
         proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
     }

}

error_log /home/www/mydomain.log info;
```

On the browser, I get a 400 Bad Request error, whether it is on `http://example.com/videos/` or even on `http://example.com/` or `http://example.com/whatever`.

When I tail the `/home/www/example.log` Nginx vhost log file, I don't get any pertinent information, or logs from other vhosts, like the following:

```
2021/07/09 12:05:49 [info] 24698#24698: *233765 client 55.36.148.206 closed keepalive connection
2021/07/09 12:06:12 [info] 24698#24698: *233772 client 217.244.66.202 closed keepalive connection
2021/07/09 12:06:13 [info] 24698#24698: *233775 client closed connection while waiting for request, client: 63.210.40.102, server: 0.0.0.0:80
```

(Note: the unique endpoint works for `/videos/` route but not for `/videos` route - this will be fixed later but anyway that shouldn't interfere with the question.)

Any idea how to debug/understand where this 400 error comes from?

Comment: Check your application logs.

Comment: Doesn't the /home/www/example.log as configured in the vhost, replace the application log?

Comment: You should hope not! How else would you be able to debug your application if you are not logging?

Comment: My question is precisely about logging. As stated, I have configured the vhost to log to /home/www/example.log, but nothing appears in the log about the 400. I'm not sure I understand your point

Comment: You seem to be confusing the nginx logs with your application's logs. These are separate and distinct.

Comment: Oh sorry I thought you were referring to another Nginx app log, not my API app served by Uvicorn. Gotcha. So actually I was assuming the error wasn't coming from the application, since I can curl it successfully, and since I was (wrongly) assuming 400s were generated by Nginx, but you are right, the error is on the app's side. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Michael Hampton's remarks, it appeared that the 400 errors were not on Nginx's side, but on the Python app's side served by Gunicorn/Uvicorn, even though the curl was working locally.

So it just needed to show the Gunicorn logs to debug it, by launching it manually with the debug logs on, this way:

```
gunicorn -k uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker --bind "0.0.0.0:8002" --log-level debug my_api.asgi:application
```